# VB.NET collection of windows

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, collections, udp-data-transfer

I would like to access a collection of windows (just windows that are currently open in the user's session).
I will use EnumerateWindows, but I don't know how I could make them as available as .NET does it for example for processes.

I would like to be able to access them as

```
For Each window in Windows
    Debug.Print window.Text
    Debug.Print window.Handle
Next
```

I guess I need a class to do that, but I don't have any idea who this is done in practice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In which language do you want this logic to be applied?

Comment: You should specify if you are talking about of WindowForms, WPF or ?... and what does it means that 'UDT' tag

Comment: The question's topic starts with "VB.NET", meaning it is about VB.NET. The question about WindowForms or WPF is irrelevant. I am talking about WINDOWS on the user's desktop. And UDT means "User Defined Type" or "structure".